# Problema com PadLeft

Tags: c#, .net, string

Estou com um problema ao utilizar o método PadLeft. Preciso colocar alguns zeros na frente de uma string, mas não estou conseguindo. Por exemplo:

```
string value = "2001795";
string newValue = value.PadLeft(5, '0');
```

Teoricamente, a string "newValue" deveria ficar com o valor "000002001795", certo? Mas isso não está funcionando...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Teoricamente, a string "newValue" deveria ficar com o valor "000002001795", certo?

Não. O `PadLeft` serve para completar uma string com um carácter qualquer, este que é passado como segundo parâmetro do método, até ela chegar no número de caracteres informado no primeiro parâmetro.

Como por exemplo:

```
var value = "123";
var newValue = value.PadLeft(5, '0');

// Saída 00123
```

Se você precisa apenas colocar 5 zeros na frente da string, só é necessário fazer uma concatenação.

```
var value = "123";
var newValue = "00000" + value;

// Saída 00000123
```

Comment: Muito obrigado a vocês! Agora entendi, eu achei que o primeiro parâmetro era a quantidade de caracteres que são inseridos. Agora entendi, muito obrigado mesmo!

Answer (score 3):

O método `PadLeft`, acrescenta caracteres a esquerda até completar sua *string* completar o número de caracteres informado, caso a *string* já possua no minimo essa quantidade de caracteres nada acontecerá.

No seu caso, ele irá acrescentar 0 a esquerda até sua *string* completar 5 caracteres, como sua variável possui 7 caracteres, não irá acontecer nada. Se você substituísse por exemplo por:

```
string value = "2001795";
string newValue = value.PadLeft(10, '0');
```

O valor de `newValue` seria `0002001795`, pois ele iria acrescentar 3 0 a esquerda até completar 10 caracteres.

Comment: Muito obrigado a vocês! Agora entendi, eu achei que o primeiro parâmetro era a quantidade de caracteres que são inseridos. Agora entendi, muito obrigado mesmo!

Answer (score 2):

O primeiro argumento é a quantidade máxima(totalWidth) que a string deve ter. Você disse que o tamanho máximo é 5, `2001795` tem mais que 5 caracteres, então não tinha que completar.

Forma correta:

```
 string newValue = value.PadLeft(12,'0');
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.padleft(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Muito obrigado a vocês! Agora entendi, eu achei que o primeiro parâmetro era a quantidade de caracteres que são inseridos. Agora entendi, muito obrigado mesmo!