# Preencher string com casas em branco

Tags: c#, string

Estou precisando formatar uma string para que a mesma contenha apenas 30 caracteres.

Caso tenha menos que trinta, deve-se completar com espaços em branco, e caso tenha mais, deve-se deixá-la apenas com 30.

Sei que deve ter uma forma de fazer +- assim:

```
string.Format("{0:                              }, item.nome");
```

Porém assim não está funcionando.

Alguma dica?

Comment: Outra duplicata: [Problema com PadLeft](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/186447/18246)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`PadRight`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/36f2hz3a(v=vs.110).aspx) para completar com espaços se a string tiver menos de 30 caracteres (ou 30, porque aí não acontece nada) e [`Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) para cortá-la caso contrário.

```
item.nome.Length <= 30 ? item.nome.PadRight(30, ' ') : item.nome.Substring(0, 30);
```

Comment: respondi na mesma hora que vocês kkkkkkk

Answer (score 3):

No `C#`, existe a função String.PadRight

> Do [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.padright(v=vs.110).aspx)
>   Retorna uma nova cadeia de caracteres de um comprimento especificado em que o final da cadeia de caracteres atual será preenchido com espaços ou com um caractere Unicode especificado.

Então, para completar com espaços, no seu caso pode usar:

```
item.nome.PadRight(30)
```

Comment: respondi na mesma hora que vocês kkkkkkk

Answer (score 1):

Consegui fazer da seguinte forma:

```
item.nome.PadRight(30, ' ');
```

PadRight completa espaços à direita, e a string ao lado (com aspas simples ao invés de duplas) deve conter o caracter que vai completar a string